# show character ASCII code and number of appearance

Tags: c

I want to make a program which reads the text from a file and shows every character, the ASCI code of each one and the number of occurrences.
I wrote this but it doesn't show the occurrences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
     FILE * pFile;

     int i=0;
     int j=0;
     char text[j];
     int ascii[256];
     int occ[256];
     int occurance=0;
     int position;
     pFile = fopen ("c:/1.in","r");
     if (pFile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
     else
     {
         while (!feof(pFile)) { 
         j++;
         text[j]=getc (pFile);
         ascii[j]= (int) text[j];
         position=ascii[j];
         occ[position]++;
     }
 
     for (i=1;i<j;i++){
         occurance=position[i]
  
         printf ("Chracter %c  has  ascii %d and occurs  %d times \n",   text[i],ascii[i],occ[occurance]  );}
     }
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Those are terrible variable names.

Comment: We would be happy to help you if you take little effort in changing those variable names with understandable ones,like what i, j, r , rr etc. does

Comment: @ValValli: You should always use long, meaningful variable names.  It is extremely important that your code be easy for people to read.

Comment: no better time to start using proper variable names, then. start now, before you get into bad habits (and bad variable naming is a VERY bad one)... or your future code is likely to show up on the dailywtf site.

Comment: ok. i.ll rewrite it in a minute. thanks guys

Comment: int j=0;
     char v[j];
is that what you want? what does it mean?

Comment: @qpcr. I don.t know the size of array because i dont know the size of the text so i guess this is the method for initialize.. Guess i.m wrong

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't see the point in this:

```
int j=0;
char text[j];
```

If you want to put every character in the file into an array then read the size of the file and `malloc()` the correct size to a pointer. But why do that anyway? If you're trying to count ever occurrence of ever character then just keep track of the possibilities.

For completeness you can use an array of 256 characters, but in reality if you're just looking at standard printable characters there should only be about 94.

This:

```
int main ()
{
  int temp = 0, i;
  int occ[256] = {0};
  FILE * pFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  if (pFile == NULL) perror("Error opening file");
  else {
     while (!feof(pFile)) { 
       temp = getc(pFile);
       if((temp < 255) && (temp >= 0)) 
         occ[temp]++;
     }
  }
//reads every character in the file and stores it in the array, then:

  for(i = 0; i<sizeof(occ)/sizeof(int); i++){
      if(occ[i] > 0)
          printf(" Char %c (ASCII %#x) was seen %d times\n", i, i, occ[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

will print every character, the ASCII code (in hex) and the number of times it showed.

An example input file of:

> fdsafcesac3sea

yeilds an output of:

```
Char 3 (ASCII 0x33) was seen 1 times
Char a (ASCII 0x61) was seen 3 times
Char c (ASCII 0x63) was seen 2 times
Char d (ASCII 0x64) was seen 1 times
Char e (ASCII 0x65) was seen 2 times
Char f (ASCII 0x66) was seen 2 times
Char s (ASCII 0x73) was seen 3 times
```

Comment: it doesn.t work.. it shows a lot of symbols... i have only  a line in document with ordinary characters

Comment: Char   (ASCII 0) was seen 70 times
 Char ☺ (ASCII 0x1) was seen 21 times
 Char ♥ (ASCII 0x3) was seen 67 times
 Char ♫ (ASCII 0xe) was seen 34 times
 Char ► (ASCII 0x10) was seen 72 times
 Char ↕ (ASCII 0x12) was seen 34 times
 Char § (ASCII 0x15) was seen 12 times
 Char ↨ (ASCII 0x17) was seen 119 times
 Char ↑ (ASCII 0x18) was seen 72 times
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @ValValli - If you coppied my code exactly it wouldn't have worked, I had a few typos in there which I've corrected. Take another look, and if it's still not working please let me know what excatly doesn't and what your text file looks like

Comment: not it still doesn.t work. let me explain you better

Read the whole file till the end char by char. Save char one by one in an array and save in other array on the ascii code position the occurance. EX : "this is an example" get "T" put it on  first position on first array, get the ASCII of T and on the second array go to position equal with value for ASCII T and incrase by one. Then display each one like you have tried

Comment: and if you cand please put the whole code without spaces. its get annoyng cuz i work at this for about 5 hours

Comment: i get this. Finaly. No need to post. Thank you everyone. the error was in declaration of arrays

Comment: @ValValli - It pretty much was the whole code, but there it is. I used a file called "test.txt" and I provided you what was in it and the output I got which seems like what you were looking for. The why you explain it, reading the full file into an array is over kill for this. If it still doesn't work I'd suspect something strange about your `1.in` file.

Answer (score 0):

Below simple logic works fine for me. Add file operations to get the `buf`.

```
int main()
{
   char buf[] = "abcaabde";
   char val[256] = {0};
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
   {
       val[buf[i]]++;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
   {
       if (val[i] != 0)
       {
           printf("%c occured %d times\n", i, val[i]); 
       }
   }

   return 0;  
}
```

Output is

```
 occured 1 times
a occured 3 times
b occured 2 times
c occured 1 times
d occured 1 times
e occured 1 times
```